# Error after having configured IIS for CF 6.1

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

I have configured IIS 7 for CF 6.1 as per the following link:

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=1&cid=224AA

But am still getting the following error:

```
Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE"
Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Detailed Error Information Module StaticFileModule Notification ExecuteRequestHandler Handler StaticFile Error Code 0x80070032
Requested URL http://127.0.0.1:80/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\index.cfm
Logon Method Anonymous
Logon User Anonymous

Most likely causes:
•The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler. Things you can try:
•If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your `.cfm` mapping to jrun isn't in place.  The tutorial isn't terribly clear about the mappings needed - there's a hint that `.cfm` needs to be added in one image (on page 7), but that's a little.. scant.  Can you confirm what's in place in IIS's "Hander Mappings" section?

Also: CF 6 is positively ancient, I'd strongly recommend running a newer version.  I believe 6 (and 7) no longer get security updates.

Comment: In Handler Mappings I can see the same as in the last image on Page 7. I mean I added 2 handlers for .cfc and .cfm. 

Actually I need to use CF 6.1 for the moment with IIS 7. I know CF6.1 is ancient but lets say for the moment I imperatively need to configure CF6.1 on IIS 7.

Pls throw some light on the error am getting.

Thx

Comment: @FlexyBoz Your handler isn't working, then.  The error means that the script handler for .cfm isn't triggering.  `The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.`

Comment: Yes but how do I make it work now? I've tried almost everything stated in the Pages on the site.

IIS does not recognise CF 6.1..Why do we need to do it manually??!